# Commutator Subgroup is a Subgroup of "$G^2$"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, derived-subgroup

Show that the commutator subgroup $G'$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup of $G^2$ defined by $G^2=\{x^2:x \in G\}$.

I've tried writing the general element of $G'$; $hgh^{-1}g^{-1}$ as the square of some element. Haven't quite found it yet. Any Hints would be appreciated!

Comment: The claim is false as written, since $G^2$ need not be a subgroup, so it does not make sense to claim that $G'$ is a "subgroup" of a set that is not a group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The claim is false as written: the subset you have labeled "$G^2$" is not necessarily a subgroup of $G$, so saying that $G'$ is a "subgroup" of something that is not even a group is incorrect. (The smallest examples of groups for which the set of squares is not a subgroup have order $16$, and there are two of them)

But I don't think that's the correct definition of $G^2$ anyway. The usual definition for not-necessarily abelian groups is: for any $n\gt 0$,
$$\begin{align*}
G^{\{n\}} &= \{g^n\mid g\in G\},\\
G^n &= \langle G^{\{n\}}\rangle = \langle g^n\mid g\in G\rangle.
\end{align*}$$

Note that $G^n$ is always normal (in fact, characteristic): because for every $x\in G$ and every element $g^n$ of its generating set, we have $xg^nx^{-1} = (xgx^{-1})^n\in G^{\{n\}}$.

Now consider $G/G^2$ (with the corrected definition). This is a group in which every element satisfies $x^2=e$, and therefore $G/G^2$ is abelian.

But $G'$ has the property that for every normal subgroup $M$ of $G$, if $G/M$ is abelian then $G'\subseteq M$. Therefore, $G'\subseteq G^2$.

Comment: Understood.Thanks a ton for the clarification and asnwer:)

Comment: @BavaneshBS and do you know about upvoting and accepting answers? Please review the FAQ if you do not.

Comment: So, how could the commutator $[g,h]=ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ be written explicitly as a product of squares?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang $ghg^{-1}h^{-1} = (gh)^2(h^{-1}g^{-1}h)^2(h^{-1})^2$. But the whole point of universal properties is to *use them*, not to ignore them and do the  work each and every time.